# Метод map для копии массива

Tags: javascript

Каким образом метод map примененный к копии массива меняет оригинал массива clients ?

```
const clients = [
  { name: 'Alex',town: 'Sitka',debt: false },
  { name: 'Bob',town: 'Phoenix',debt: false },
  { name: 'Pol',town: 'LosAngeles',debt: true },
  { name: 'Roy',town: 'Buckeye',debt: false },
  { name: 'Brad',town: 'Dallas',debt: false },
  { name: 'Leny',town: 'Charlotte',debt: true },
  { name: 'Peny',town: 'Hibbing',debt: false },
]

const clientsCopy1 = clients.slice();// делаем копию массива clients;
const clientsCopy2 = [...clientsCopy1]; // делаем копию массива clientsCopy1 
const clientsCopy3 = clientsCopy2.map(i => { // перебираем вторую копию методом map
  i.name = i.name.toUpperCase()
  return i;
})

console.log(clients); // исходный массив тоже изменился!
Использование других способов копирования дает тот-же результат.

Такое поведение только с методом map. 
При модификации копий массивов другими способами, исходный массив остается 
без изменений.
```

Comment: видимо потому, что *объекты* (те, из которых массив состоит), передаются по ссылки всё же................попробуй `clients.splice();` вместо `clients.slice();`

Comment: а это - что делать :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object/30042948#30042948

Comment: вот кстати в доках https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice  .....цитата описания метода slice: "Элементы исходного массива копируются в новый массив по следующим правилам:

Ссылки на объекты (но не фактические объекты): метод slice() копирует ссылки на объекты в новый массив. И оригинал, и новый массив ссылаются на один и тот же объект. То есть, если объект по ссылке будет изменён, изменения будут видны и в новом, и в исходном массивах."......... всё по правилам

Comment: Да, спасибо! splice работает. Пробовал копировать еще Array.from() и [].concat() - не работает. Splice не пробовал.
С другой стороны, если копировать с помощью slice и применить метод filter , исходный массив не меняется. Возможно в механизме реализации map  еще дело?

Comment: @Lex со splice, в зависимости от задачи, может тоже кое-что не получится. На всякий случай взгляни сюда: https://stackoverflow.com/q/597588/6104996  там можно будет что-то выбрать

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, есть в чем покопаться:)

Comment: Кажется так будет проще: `const clientsCopy = clients.map(client => ({ ...client, name: client.name.toUpperCase() }));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.slice не копирует объекты внутри массива. Он копирует размер массива и ссылки на объекты которые лежат в массиве.

Чтобы сделать полную копию надо превратить в JSON и распарсить обратно. Это самый быстрый способ, но он не позволяет сохранить информацию о классах (однако, вам тут это и не надо).

```
const clientsCopy1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clients));
```